# C# code execution stops without any exception

Tags: c#

I have a C# Console application with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and [Colorful.Console](http://colorfulconsole.com/) 1.2.6 (I downgraded from 1.2.9 because I have another project with 1.2.6 which works flawlessly).
I have this class for logging:

```
static class Log
{
    public enum LogLevel { INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, ERROR = 2, VERBOSE = 3 }
    private static void log(LogLevel logLevel, string msg)
    {
        Color[] colors = { Color.Cyan, Color.Orange, Color.Red, Color.LimeGreen };
        Console.WriteLineFormatted($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}][{logLevel.ToString()}] {{0}}", Color.Yellow, new Formatter(msg, colors[(int)logLevel]));
    }

    public static void i(string msg)
    {
        log(LogLevel.INFO, msg);
    }
    public static void w(string msg)
    {
        log(LogLevel.WARNING, msg);
    }
    public static void e(string msg)
    {
        log(LogLevel.ERROR, msg);
    }
    public static void v(string msg)
    {
        log(LogLevel.VERBOSE, msg);
    }
}
```

When I use `Log#i` from the `Program#Main` method it works perfectly but if I call `Log#i` from another calss it displays the line and the program completly stops without error (and it doesn't crash) at

```
Console.WriteLineFormatted($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}][{logLevel.ToString()}] {{0}}", Color.Yellow, new Formatter(msg, colors[(int)logLevel]));
```

line, the application stops responding (but it doesn't write it in the title bar).
The program looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static OverlayForm overlayForm;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.i("A");
        Log.i("B");

        overlayForm = new OverlayForm();
    }
}

internal class OverlayForm : Form
{
    public OverlayForm()
    {
        Log.i("AA");
        Log.i("BB");
    }
}
```

and the output is this:

```
[10:12:36][INFO] A 
[10:12:36][INFO] B 
[10:12:36][INFO] AA
```

I already tried to wrap the mentioned line inside a try catch block but no difference, I also tried in VS2019 in the exception settings checking all the exceptions to break at.

Comment: Have you checked Windows event logger?

Comment: Programs don't just stop for no reason, they crash or the logical execution ends. Firstly as been suggested check your windows event logs, secondly, debug this.

Comment: What should I look for or where should I look for in the event viewer? From debugging everything I know is that the problematic line is `Console.WriteLineFormatted(...)` because the execution stops at this line and I can't catch any exception and I can't see anything in the debugger.

Comment: So a `try catch` around `Console.WriteLineFormatted(...)` catches nothing?

Comment: Exactly, the line is displayed in the console, but the execution doesn't continue

Comment: Just trying to understand this better, if you break point this line `Log.i("BB");` it never gets there, but it will hit the line before?

Comment: Yes, because the `Log#log` method doesn't ends. The last break point hits the `Console.WriteLineFormatted(...)` line but doesn't hit the `}` (the end of the method)

Answer (score 0):

If you writing to console from a single thread, then try to use this instead:

```
private static void log(LogLevel logLevel, string msg)
    {
        ConsoleColor[] colors = { ConsoleColor.Cyan, ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Green };

        Console.ForegroundColor = colors[(int)logLevel];
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), logLevel, msg);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
```